# Load widget with signal-slot defintions from UI file in main window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am having difficulties to load a widget generated by Qt Designer into my MainWindow. It fails when I have also defined signals and slots in the UI file.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import uic as pyuic

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.uifile = 'serialTandemGUI.ui'
        self.form_widget = pyuic.loadUi(self.uifile)
        _widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        _layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(_widget)
        _layout.addWidget(self.form_widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(_widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    app.exec_()
```

The error I get is:
`AttributeError: 'QWidget' object has no attribute 'init'`

Is it possible at all to inherit a widget this way? Tia!

**Edit:**
Here's a simple UI file with a clicked() signal to demonstrate. It works as long as no signal definitions have been made (i.e. really just UI, but that is only half of the work, or even less).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
     <property name="title">
      <string>GroupBox</string>
     </property>
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
        <property name="text">
         <string>PushButton</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>pushButton</sender>
   <signal>clicked()</signal>
   <receiver>Form</receiver>
   <slot>init()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>203</x>
     <y>162</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>396</x>
     <y>201</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
 <slots>
  <slot>init()</slot>
 </slots>
</ui>
```

Comment: share the .ui .........

Comment: Any ui file with a signal-slot definition does. Not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

When you have created the .ui you have only pointed out that there is a connection between the clicked signal and the `init` method of the widget, but when you load it using `loadUi()` and do not pass it as a second parameter a QWidget will use the base class of the design, in your case QWidget, which clearly has no "init" method throwing you that error.

**Solution:**

You must create a class that inherits from QWidget and has the `init` method, and then use `loadUi()` to fill it out.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic as pyuic


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        uifile = os.path.join(current_dir, "serialTandemGUI.ui")
        pyuic.loadUi(uifile, self)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def init(self):
        print("init")


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.form_widget = Widget()
        _widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        _layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(_widget)
        _layout.addWidget(self.form_widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(_widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() or QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That answers it completely, thank you very much! I've tried to have the related slot methods in the main window, but having it in the corresponding widget class is also making everything much clearer.

Comment: Could you please explain why it is favorable to have the @QtCore.pyqtSlot() decorator? It also works without.

Comment: @damada read https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator